# picking items from list of list

Tags: python, list

I have a list in the following form:

```
l0=[[('x0', 2), ('x1', 3)], [('x2', 5), ('x3', 7), ('x4', 1)]]
```

How one turns this into:

```
l=[2,3,5,7,1]
```

I tried:

```
l=[x[1] for x in l0]
```

which gives:

```
#[('x1', 3), ('x3', 7)]
```

**Edit:** 
In order not to lose track of elements is there also anyway to have the output as:

```
l=[[2,3],[5,7,1]]
```

So one does not use flattening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: terrible name of variable `l0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your new question, you can use a nested comprehension.

```
lst0 = [[('x0', 2), ('x1', 3)], [('x2', 5), ('x3', 7), ('x4', 1)]]
lst = [[t[1] for t in u] for u in lst0]
print(lst)
```

**output**

```
[[2, 3], [5, 7, 1]]
```

I changed the names of the lists since `l0` and `l` aren't very readable in most fonts: the `l` is too similar to `1`.

---

As an alternative, you could do this using `map` although Guido isn't fond of this construction:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst0 = [[('x0', 2), ('x1', 3)], [('x2', 5), ('x3', 7), ('x4', 1)]]
print([list(map(itemgetter(1), u)) for u in lst0])
```

In Python 2, you can omit the `list` wrapper:

```
print [map(itemgetter(1), u) for u in lst0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an extra loop to your comprehension:

```
l0=[[('x0', 2), ('x1', 3)], [('x2', 5), ('x3', 7), ('x4', 1)]]

l=[x[1] for i in l0 for x in i]
print(l)
# [2, 3, 5, 7, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the list and append it to a new one.

```
l0=[[('x0', 2), ('x1', 3)], [('x2', 5), ('x3', 7), ('x4', 1)]]

out = []
for a in l0:
    out.append([x[0] for x in a])
print(out)
```

Comment: this is basically a non-compressed version of @FHTMitchell's solution

Comment: A simple more readable version yes, his answer wasn't listed here as I was typing it out.

Answer (score -1):

you first have to flatten the list like this 
`flat_list = [item for sublist in l0 for item in sublist]`
and then do your thing 
`l=[x[1] for x in flat_list]`

Comment: thanks is there also anyway to make it like l=[[2,3],[5,7,1]]?

Comment: @Will better to edit your question that put this as a comment

Comment: yes, it would go something like this [[x[1] for x in sub_list] for sub_list in l0]

Answer (score -2):

try to use the index, your l0 is a list: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

```
l0=[[('x0', 2), ('x1', 3)], [('x2', 5), ('x3', 7), ('x4', 1)]]
l=(l0[0][0][1],l0[0][1][1],l0[1][0][1],l0[1][1][1],l0[1][2][1])
print(l)
```

> > > (2, 3, 5, 7, 1)

Comment: Ok, that works, as long as the sizes of the lists don't change. But it's too verbose, and too easy to make a mistake with all of those indices.

Comment: Yes of course he has to find a general formula (loop) to find this result